# Problemas com NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, front-end

Alguém pode me ajudar com este site. A parte frontal exibe os preços só que logo abaixo exibe novamente com NaN. Quando entra em qualquer produto, o NaN desaparece. Alguma dica de como posso resolver isso?

Algum truque para "ocultar" o NaN na tela frontal seria interessante.

O site: https://jsfiddle.net/brunoarchanjo88/

Comment: Já tem um "3x sem juros" mostrando acima. Onde tem o NaN seria o mesmo valor?

Comment: Sim, tem dois "sem juros" na tela frontal, sendo um normal e o outro com "NaN". Quero eliminar esse com o "NaN" mas não consigo de jeito nenhum! Esse que está com o NaN é o mesmo que esta dentro de cada produto. Ou seja, ele imprime certo lá dentro e lá fora ele imprime errado

Comment: Veja a resposta que postei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitua o código deste bloco:

```
   // Imprime os preços internos
// Aqui é para limpar os excessos do setInterval
    var counter = 0
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if($(".ecwid-productBrowser-details").is(":visible")){
            mostra = "";
        }else{
            mostra = "display: none;";
        }
    if(counter >= 0){
      $("h5").remove()
    }
    counter++
// Aqui pega as classes para serem tratadas 
        var demo = $('div.ecwid-productBrowser-price');
            demo.each(function() {
            var valor = parseInt(this.innerHTML.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',','.').substr(2) / 3, 10).toFixed(2).replace('.',',')
                $(this).after("<h5 class='demo' style='"+mostra+"color: #e9d0ba;font-size:15px;'>3x de " +valor+ " sem juros </h5>")
        })        
        }, 1000)
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7tgas48/4/)**

Comment: Já havia feito isso, funciona, só que daí quando entro nos produtos da loja, some a frase "3x sem juros" de lá de dentro! Tem que ter a frase lá dentro e lá fora

Comment: Entendi. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: @BamDeveloper Resposta atualizada.

Comment: @BamDeveloper Veja agora.

Comment: Agora sim. Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @BamDeveloper Legal!